# Spark Physical Plan: meaning of number of input batches in ColumnarToRow operator

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm looking at a physical plan generated by running Spark query. The query reads a parquet file and does some aggregation. In the physical plan, there is an operator called `ColumnarToRow`, and it has a statistics called "number of input batches". I'm curious how is this number of input batches determined? It seems to depend on the number of row groups in the parquet file, but not entirely.

Here is my code:

```
df1 = spark.read.parquet('data/')
           .select('col1')
           .groupby('col1')
           .agg(f.count('col1').alias('ct'))
           .toPandas()
```

Here is the ColumnarToRow operator statistics:

```
ColumnarToRow
number of output rows: 327,069
number of input batches: 80
```

Answer (score 3):

The existence of this `ColumnarToRow` block comes from the fact that you're reading in a parquet file. Parquet files are stored in a column-oriented fashion, which brings a bunch of advantages with it.

But inside of Apache Spark, RDDs are stored in a row-oriented fashion. This enables us to do classical operations like `map`, `reduce`, `groupBy`, ... efficiently.

Now, if we have a quick look at the source code that generates these numbers you are talking about (using Spark v3.3.1), we see the following in [`Columnar.scala`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0d0918b1e968789657d9ae6e49d57fdb7c529434/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/Columnar.scala#L82-L101):

```scala
override lazy val metrics: Map[String, SQLMetric] = Map(
  "numOutputRows" -> SQLMetrics.createMetric(sparkContext, "number of output rows"),
  "numInputBatches" -> SQLMetrics.createMetric(sparkContext, "number of input batches")
)

override def doExecute(): RDD[InternalRow] = {
  val numOutputRows = longMetric("numOutputRows")
  val numInputBatches = longMetric("numInputBatches")
  // This avoids calling `output` in the RDD closure, so that we don't need to include the entire
  // plan (this) in the closure.
  val localOutput = this.output
  child.executeColumnar().mapPartitionsInternal { batches =>
    val toUnsafe = UnsafeProjection.create(localOutput, localOutput)
    batches.flatMap { batch =>
      numInputBatches += 1
      numOutputRows += batch.numRows()
      batch.rowIterator().asScala.map(toUnsafe)
    }
  }
}
```

So we see that the `numInputBatches` val is being incremented (`numInputBatches += 1`) within the `mapPartitionsInternal` function. That means this `numInputBatches` signifies the number of partitions that your parquet file that you're reading has!

You should be able to verify this by doing the following in a (py)spark shell:

```
spark.read.parquet('data/').rdd.getNumPartitions()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help! Let me take a look and digest a bit~

Comment: You're welcome! Let me know the outcome, I'm interested myself :)